# php integer value is not showing as aspected

Tags: php, integer

While coding I got an unexpected result.

I'm unsure how to ask this question so I'll put in my code and result:

```
$variable = 012;
$variable2 = 12;
$variable3 = '012';
```

When I echo out the variables:

Expected result:

```
$variable: 12 
$variable2: 12 
$variable3: 012
```

Result:

```
$variable: 10 
$variable2: 12 
$variable3: 012
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Numbers defined with a leading zero are treated as octal, so 012 is octal 12 which is 1x8+2 = decimal 10; numbers defined without a leading zero are decimal; strings with a leading zero are still strings

Comment: Can see your the code that works on these variables

Comment: can you provide your code

Comment: He has provided his code

Comment: Not sure what to do with my question should I close or delete it since it is possible duplicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) of the integers of php

Then you see the following:

```
To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0
```

So octal 12 is decimal 10

---

Little bit more info of the docs

```
<?php
$a = 1234; // decimal number
$a = -123; // a negative number
$a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)
$a = 0x1A; // hexadecimal number (equivalent to 26 decimal)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$variable is Octal 
$variable2 is int
$variable3 is string
```